# Copy-Item destination path ignored within remote server powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a folder backup in a remote server. Basically I want to copy the folder `c:\Services\MainService` and its contents to this other folder `c:\Services\backups\backup_001` within the remote server.

I am using a `New-PSSession` object to connect to the remote server. The account I am using is a `Built-In/Administrator` in the remote server.

Then I am using a powershell script in my local machine which has the following command to execute the copy-item in the remote server:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $connection -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item -Path C:\Services\MainService -Destination C:\Services\backups\backup_001 -Recurse -Force }
```

After executing the script I logged-in into the remote server and I didn't see the files in the destination path I specified in the `copy-item` command. Instead I saw the original folder inside the local user folder of the account used to connect to the remove server:`C:\Users\{accountname}\Documents\MainService`

The `-Destination` path is being ignored. I have been trying with different accounts but I get the same result every time. All the accounts I have been using to connect to the remote server through `New-PSSession` are `BUILT-IN/Administrator` in the remote server.

Comment: When using paths I'd start with these two practices:
Use quotes and use a final slash in PS `"C:\Services\backups\backup_001\"`

Comment: When I put the path in a variable `$path = "C:\Services\backups\backup_001\"` and then I use it `-Destination $path` it does not work but if put the path directly `"C:\Services\backups\backup_001\"` it works, I am getting the path from a function so I cannot use the path directly, do you know why it wont work if in a variable?

Comment: Without seeing the variable and function it's hard to guess by you can also wrap the variable the quotes like `"$myVar"`